# Can't find the Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am pretty sure I installed VS 2012 Express on my new laptop a month ago. I even posted on Facebook about how I didn't like the default themes because the window borders were too light in color.

Now, I can't seem to find the VS 2012 Express installation. Where should I look?

I've looked for devenv.exe or any exe under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common\IDE` and in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common\IDE`.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I found it. The exe name is VWDExpress.exe and it is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common\IDE`

Comment: This was close enough to get me started, I found it at `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Ultimate version go to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE
```

and look for "devenv"  with visualStudio Icon .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found it in

> Local Disk > Program Files 86 > Common7 > IDE > WDExpress

It wasn't an .exe when I found it, it was an application that I launched.